# Queries over large data tables

Tags: performance, powerbi

We have a large dataset of unstructured data (Azure Blob) and have started noticing that refreshing our model gets quite slow after a few thousand records are being loaded.

Our current query structure is:

```
#"Load Data"
    Loads data from the Azure Blob, ~1000 files
    Parses the files into a table with 3 columns (of list/record types which can be further expanded), ~700k rows

#"Sessions"
    Reference #"Load Data"
    Expand all 'Session' related columns

#"Users"
    Reference #"Load Data"
    Expand all 'User' related columns

#"Events"
    Reference #"Load Data"
    Expand all 'Event' related columns

#"Events By Name"
    Reference #"Events"
    Groups by 'event.name'- generates a column of tables to each event type's events and properties (these vary between events)

#"Event Name1" (2, 3, etc. one table per event type)
    Reference #"Events by Name"
    Expands that event name's Table, and generates a table with event.id and each of the properties for that event type
```

While running this and watching the resource monitor, the memory usage goes through the roof, and eventually tons of Hard Faults leading to Disk usage. From looking at the query execution popup, it seems a bunch of queries kick-off and run in parallel.

If I load the data from a local folder, they seem to all be fetching data, going through the files and loading the referenced common queries in parallel. I believe this is what's causing the memory usage to go haywire, the disk to kick in, and the queries to take hours to run.

I assumed referenced queries would run once first, and then have their resulting tables referenced by individual queries using it, but that doesn't seem to be the case. I've also tried using Table.Buffer as the last step of #"Load Data" and #"Events", in an attempt to make those queries be computed once and then shared across dependents, but that only seemed to make it worse. Are there ways to:

- Make a query only run once, and have it's result passed forward to any queries referencing it
- Prevent queries from running in parallel, and run sequentially instead

Am I just looking at this the wrong way? A lot of 'performance' articles I found only mention structuring your queries to allow Query Folding. However this is not a possibility for our current case, as the Azure Blob storage really just stores 'blob' files which have to be loaded and parsed locally.

It's being a real struggle to get these queries running on our current 700k test events, and we expect it to go up to millions in the real environment. Is our only option to treat the blobs and push the data into an SQL database and link our model to that instead?

Answer (score 0):

You process your data first and store it into a table on your DB, and then use this table as a data source to your model. Refresh data in the source table by running a job which runs on a scheduled interval and update the table.